# How to merge subtitles with video using mkvmerge with special characters?

Tags: video, subtitle

When I use `mkvmerge` to make a hardcoded subtitle with special characters as ã, á, à, â it replaces it with "?".

I use the following command to embed subtitles:

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv video.mp4 subtitles.srt
```

`mkvmerge` is very fast, so I want to keep using it, but how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Speaking from experience, `ffmpeg` is also very fast, if you use the `-c:a copy -c:v copy` flags. This prevents it from re-encoding the video and just adds the subtitles to the container.  Info on how to add subtitles using ffmpeg is here if anyone is interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33289845/5075214

Comment: @blendenzo Does ffmpeg deal with special characters?

Comment: Yes, it does. Special characters are displayed based on the character encoding of your .srt file. So if ffmpeg doesn't give you the expected output, you just use the `-sub_charenc` flag and specify the appropriate encoding. Example: if your .srt file is saved as utf8, you would use `-sub_charenc UTF-8`. Be aware: the wiki says the character encoding flag has to come immediately before the subtitle file in your command for it to work.  More here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/subtitle_options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1 - Save .srt subtitle with UTF-8 encoding:**

*This is step is useful to play your movie on some smartv's or DVDs.*

Open subtitle with `gedit`**>** save file as... **>** choose `UTF-8 character encoding`.

**2 - Discover the abreviation of your language on `mkvmerge`:**

`mkvmerge --list-languages`

In my case, `pt`.

**3 - Hardcode the subtitle**

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv video.mp4 subtitles.srt --chapter-language  pt
```